# Optimizing Flash CC and swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, optimization, flash-cc

Good evening programmers.

Please do not laugh, but by flash file is 270 MB.

My artists have gave me their final art to me via illustrator.

What I have been doing is opening up the illustrator file and copy and pasting the objects in to flash.

I have movieclips, buttons, tweens and graphics in my library ( 556 items)

How can I optimize my Flash because the swf file is 30MB.

I also have 10 AS3 files, my code doesn't slow the file down, it must be the images.

Thank you.

I've deleted the un used files from my library and have saved the update flash file as another .FLa file.

Hasn't decreased the file that much, still the swf is quite slow when it comes to gameplay.

Comment: did you copy it as vector objects?

Comment: default settings, you know when you copy and past from ill* to flash, I didn't touch nothing but the ok button.

Comment: did you by chance select "Paste as bitmap" in the dialog that opens when you are trying to paste the asset into flash?

Comment: this is the flash file! You will see it takes ages to load!
http://www.computing.northampton.ac.uk/~13422770/gameGroup/KDV2.swf

and the first level is slow

Comment: If you go in to your publish settings check 'generate size report'. When you publish then, there will be a report in the output panel that shows the sizes of everything published.

Comment: You appear opposed to bitmaps but you should give them a try.  The bitmap rendering engine in AS3 is fast.  If MS Paint comes to mind when you hear 'bitmap' then I highly suggest researching them and throwing out that bad association.

Comment: @E10 please don't think of me as a little naive kid, I understand what you mean and yes bitmaps are faster I know.

Comment: But yes, I will take your advice and read up on action script 3, ps. I don't think bad of MS paint.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for panicking.

When you have complicated shapes and vectors flash takes its time to render the graphics, hence the pause between one frame to another.

To have solved this I had first broke apart the shape and optimized it.

But you see this didn't optimize it to an extent.

The files my artists supplied me with were 100mb - 200mb per file size.

So instead of importing it from Ill to Flash *wich was naive* I had exported the file to a PNG , which is more than a JPEG but has properties such as transparent background and quality.

What I have done is replaced all my imported images with the PNG version of that image.

Since the PNG is a flat image, it means that FLASH doesn't have to render as much.

Thank you for your comments.